# PHP Datetime Sub

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this datetime:sub to work. What's wrong with it?

**PHP**

```
//Calculate working hrs
$usr_stamp_in = new DateTime($row['usr_stamp_in']);
$usr_stamp_out = new DateTime($row['usr_stamp_out']);
$sum_time = $usr_stamp_in->diff($usr_stamp_out);

//Overtime
$tot_overtime = $sum_time;
$overtime = new DateTime($tot_overtime);
$overtime->sub(new DateInterval('T8H'));

$sum_time->format('%h tim %I min'); //Echo this will work
$overtime->format('%h'); //Echo this won't work
```

Comment: Didn't you already asked a very similar question already in the last few hours?

Comment: How does it not work? What result do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: @Rizier123 Not really...

Comment: What are sample values for `$row['usr_stamp_in']` and `$row['usr_stamp_out']`?

Comment: $John Well, if i do echo sum_time. I got "5tim 23min" for example. But overtime, just gives me fatal error,

Comment: @JohnConde it looks like: 2015-02-02 06:11:51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) it's apparent that `DateTime::diff` returns an instance of `DateInterval`:

```
//    \/Return type\/
public DateInterval DateTimeInterface::diff ( DateTimeInterface $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = false ] )
```

the `DateInterval::format` method works with `%<placeholder>` format specifiers, this is also [covered by the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). This explains why your `$sum_overtime->format()` call works:

```
$sum_time->format('%h tim %I min');//%h is a valid DateInterval format
```

However `$overtime` is an instance of `DateTime`, so you'll need to drop the `%` in your format string, and use the correct format. Again, [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) contain all the info you need.

## TL;TR You need this:

```
$overtime->format('G');//G is valid for DateTime, equivalent to %h in a DateInterval::format call
```

The format specifiers for `DateTime::format` are listed on [the `date` function docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)